# 4D rotations of 600-cell to make cell centered stereographic projection

Tags: geometry, projection, rotation

I have made a 600-cell wireframe model from Eric Weinsteins' 2/13/14 600-cell notebook *(600-cell: a regular polytope, 4D, analogous to the icosahedron, with 600 tetrahedral cells, 120 vertices, 720 edges)* in *Mathematica*, projected it onto the circumscribing unit sphere (it originally had a vertex at `{0,0,0,1},` and rotated it so that the center of a tetrahedral face is centered on `{0,0,0,1}.` When I make a stereo-graphic projection using `{0,0,0,1}` as the north pole, it looks correct: the 3 edges nearest to `{0,0,0,1}` are largest. But I want to rotate the 600-cell to make the *center* of the tetrahedral cell, not the face, centered on `{0,0,0,1}`. I can't figure out how to do this. I'm using the `RotationMatrix[{vec1, vec2}]` command, where mapping the vertices moves `vec1` to `vec2`. What should the 4D vectors be, and why?

If it helps, the first rotations to get the face centered on `{0,0,0,1}` were made by this code:

```
θ = FaceEdgeAngl["Icosahedron"];
rotate4[obj_, vec1_, vec2_] := 
   Map[(RotationMatrix[{vec1, vec2}] . #)&, obj, {1}]
vertsrot = 
  rotate4[
     rotate4[vertic, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/5], Sin[Pi/5], 0, 0}], 
     {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}];
```

Comment: Hello ! Please, refer to the help centre, specifically -- proper code formatting guidelines, markdown formatting, question tags, etc.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you having trouble computing the center of a tetrahedral cell?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what vectors to put in to rotate the 600-cell vertices so that the center of the tetrahedral cell will center on {0,0,0,1}. Yes! Thank you Igor. Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationMatrix.html),
`RotationMatrix[{source, destin}]` creates a rotation matrix that will rotate the vector `source` to the direction of vector `destin`. Let's apply this to your problem: rotate a face-centered projection to a cell-centered projection. Here `destin` is the origin

```
destin = {0,0,0,1};
```

and we need to determine the `source` vector, i.e., the vector at the center of some cell. Locate four vertices `{vert1, vert2, vert3, vert4}` of any cell (for example 4 of the 5 vertices closest to `{0,0,0,1}`). This may be the difficult part. Once you have found the vertices, just set

```
source = vert1 + vert2 + vert3 + vert4;
mat = RotationMatrix[{source, destin}];
```

Disclaimer: I do not know Wolfram Language; please feel free to correct language errors.

Comment: Fritz, thank you! It's clear when I think about it. I was able to write a subroutine to find vertices near the center of one face (at {0,0,01} with distances less than the edge distance of the 600-cell.  There were 5 (the three face vertices, and the vertices of the tetrahedrons on each side of the face) Eliminating one of these, I was able to rotate the cell to obtain the cell centered projection requested. Thanks again!